# Unable to access “Drive:”

Tags: linux, mount

I've installed both windows 8 and Linux 3.8.0-35-generic on my Laptop.
I'm unable to access the other drives other than one in which Linux has been installed.
It is showing following error. Casket is name of the partition.

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/rancher/Casket: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/rancher/Casket"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I thought shutting down windows properly would solve the problem ,but no change.
Is there any other way to shut down windows properly. Or any other way to access the contents of the drives.

Comment: drives (like `C:` or `D:` on Windows) don't exist on Linux and other Unixes. Only [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) that you can [mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the suggestion at the bottom of that error message - mounting the filesystem read-only?

```
sudo mount -o ro -t auto /dev/sda4 /media/rancher/Casket
```

Or just add the `-o ro` to your `/etc/fstab` file for the `/dev/sda4`.

Comment: This is what it is showing.`rancher@PRIME:~$ sudo mount -o ro -t auto /dev/sda4 /media/rancher/Casket
[sudo] password for rancher: 
fuse: failed to access mountpoint /media/rancher/Casket: No such file or directory`. Casket is different partition but i don't know why it is showing(in error) it under rancher directory.

Comment: Mount to another directory instead